# How to save a trained model in 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have successfully run the [Image Captioning with Attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/sequences/image_captioning) example from Tensorflow. 
Now I want to save the trained model, how do I do that?

Comment: Did you check the docs?
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models

Comment: Yes, I managed to save and restore model in that example. But I don't understand how to save the model in the "Image Captioning with Attention" example.